# How to view standard field mapping and how to add custom field mapping in Email-to-Case?

Tags: case, email2case, field-mapping

I am able to view case fields mapping like below:

[image]

There is only:

- case owner
- case priority
- case origin
- case record type

But how to know if there is more field mapped in case object. 
For Example:

- Email Subject --> Case Subject
- Email Body --> Case Description
- Sender Email Address --> Web Email
- Sender Name --> Web Name

I'm getting above mapping from testing send email-to-case record 
But how to get above mapping information in salesforce setup? Is there any documentation on these case mapping fields?

Also, I want to add custom mapping and put it to custom field:

- Email header --> Email_Header__c

Is this custom field mapping possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to map custom/Standard fields in Salesforce in Email to Case.

You need to use trigger and parse the message body to get the content and then need to populate the data.